# Image Classification - What is pixel depth?

Tags: image, scipy, deep-learning, pixel

I am following the Deep Learning course on Udacity. I am slightly confused about `pixel depth` and how it is being used in below code:

```
image_size = 28  # Pixel width and height.
pixel_depth = 255.0  # Number of levels per pixel.

image_data = (ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float) -
                      pixel_depth / 2) / pixel_depth
```

Can someone explain me why we are doing `pixel_depth / 2) / pixel_depth` while reading the image into N-d array?

Comment: I assume the image can contain the values in `[0, 1]` or `[0, 255]`, that's what they call the depth

Comment: Oh I see, makes sense. But why the `pixel_depth / 2) / pixel_depth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depth in CV just refers to the data type. Depth of 255.0 implies 8-bits for each pixel and so on.

```
pixel_depth / 2) / pixel_depth
```

This bit of code seems a little weird at first but it's purpose is to normalize the image to a range of -0.5 to 0.5, which is a common tactic to simplify image processing.

Answer (score 1):

Pixel depth is the number of values that a pixel can take. For 8-bits images, this is 256 (but they use 255 here).

The code here is used to normalize and center the pixel values into the interval [-0.5,0.5].